# Infinite loop occuring while using <s:action struts2 tag

Tags: struts2

Is there any solution to the following Struts 2 issue yet?

[link text](http://issues.apache.org/struts/browse/TILES-418)

Thanks
Chaitanya

Comment: according to the bug report that only happens in Tiles 2.1. which version of struts are you using? Struts 2.1.8 (latest) comes with tiles 2.0.6.  upgrade your jars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade Struts 2 jars to 2.1.8